# Dangerous symbol names that begin with a lowercase letter

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

I am looking for a full list of dangerous symbol names that begin with a lowercase letter in *Mathematica*.

At this moment I know three such names: `min`, `max` and `lim`. These names appear in the `LimitsPositioningTokens` list and [are being treated as operators at least when they are entered in the FrontEnd with a superscript](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/HIglQvgF2Ac/Qg2oFN4RZJ0J):

```
In[3]:= Options[$FrontEnd,LimitsPositioningTokens]
Out[3]= {LimitsPositioningTokens->{\[Sum],\[Product],\[Intersection],
         \[Union],\[UnionPlus],\[Wedge],\[Vee],lim,max,min,\[CirclePlus],
         \[CircleMinus],\[CircleTimes],\[CircleDot]}}
```

[image]

For example, type in the FrontEnd the following (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+^ for making superscript - it is important!):

```
In[1]:= max^n+4
(max^n+4)//HoldComplete//FullForm
Out[1]= 4 max^n
Out[2]//FullForm= HoldComplete[Times[Power[max,n],Plus[4]]]
```

[image: screen]

You see that `max^n+4` is interpreted as `4*max^n` in this case.

Can anyone explain what `LimitsPositioningTokens` option really does?

Are there other dangerous symbols that begin with a lowercase letter in *Mathematica*?

Comment: To be sure I was seeing it accurately, I ran `FullForm[max^n + 4]` (where the superscript `^` was generated as above) and I got `Times[4, Power[max,n]]`. It seems like the worst sort of bug.

Comment: @rcollyer Alexey Perhaps you should post $Version and $System as it seems to be version/system related. Both on a pc and mac running M8 I couldn't confirm this bug (see below).

Comment: `$Version = 7.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (February 19, 2009)` and `$System = Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)`.

Comment: @Sjoerd I have checked this on versions 7.0.1 and 5.2 for Windows. In both cases the problem persists.

Comment: Well, it looks like it has been solved in 8.0.1 then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot confirm the problem you report. Besides, the tokens you've found seem to be strings rather than symbols.

[image]

This is on win7-64/M8.0.1, my wife's mac lion/M8 doesn't show it either.

The fact that they are strings seems to be consistent with the description on the doc page of `LimitsPositioning`

> LimitsPositioningTokens is a Cell option which can be set to a list of
>   forms for which LimitsPositioning->True should be used.

All examples given there use strings.

---

**Update** to illustrate the point made in the comments below

This is with the standard `LimitsPositioningTokens` setting in $FrontEnd:

[image]

and this is with `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, LimitsPositioningTokens -> {}]`:

[image]

**Please note that the $FrontEnd setting with SetOptions is sticky.** It is likely that yours isn't at default anymore. Use the option inspector to return `LimitsPositioningTokens` to its default value (search for `LimitsPositioningTokens` with Global Settings on and remove the cross next to the variable if there is any).

Comment: All tokens in the list of the `LimitsPositioningTokens` option are strings.

Comment: @rcollyer is that a typo or is there a new version 7.1 out?  I didn't get the memo.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, under the About menu: it gave 7.01.0, I dropped the first zero. Under the system information it generates, it puts the creation date as Feb 2009.

Comment: @alexey I mean, as strings they don't pollute symbol namespace. So I don't think your max problem derives (directly) from `LimitsPositioningTokens`.

Comment: @Sjoerd `LimitsPositioningTokens` is related only to the FrontEnd, not to the kernel. It will not pollute the kernel's namespace. As I understand, this option controls how the FrontEnd interprets user input. If I evaluate `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,LimitsPositioningTokens->{}]` and then enter `max^n+4` using Ctrl+^ for creating the superscript the problem disappear in v. 7.0.1.

Comment: @alexey From reading the documentation and my own experimentation it was my understanding that this option has to do with _formatting_ not _interpretation_. Some elements like the sigma for sum have subscripts and/or superscripts that go to bottom and top, resp. of that element when this element appears in-line, but that go to bottom-right and top-right when used in a division. `LimitsPositioningTokens` determines which elements will do this. Try, for instance, Limit[1/x, x -> \[Infinity]] and 1/Limit[1/x, x -> \[Infinity]]. Don't execute, but change to TraditionalForm.

Comment: @Sjoerd Entering `Limit[1/x, x -> [Infinity]]` and `1/Limit[1/x, x -> [Infinity]]` and converting them to `TraditionalForm Display` via `Cell|Convert to` gives nothing unexpected: both are formatted identically (converting to `TraditionalForm` does nothing). I do not understand what you are trying to show with this example. I think that the examples in my question clearly show that in version 7.01 the option `LimitsPositioningTokens` affects *interpretation* of the input. Do you mean that this behavior is a bug and in really it should affect only formatting? Your example does not clarify this.

Comment: @Alexey the backslash before [Infinity] disappeared in the copy&paste process. Could you try `TraditionalForm` again, but now with the backslash present? Indeed SetOption[$FrontEnd,LimitsPositioningTokens->{}] changes the behavior of the formatting to not go to the sideways style in divisions. Take care to set it to the original set first. More info at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LimitsPositioning.html

Comment: @Sjoerd Really, there is no any difference in how these two expressions are converted to the `TraditionalForm` via `Cell|Convert to|TraditionalForm` menu token in version 7.0.1! Here are the expressions: `Limit[1/x, x -> \[Infinity]]` and `1/Limit[1/x, x -> \[Infinity]]`. And evaluating `SetOption[$FrontEnd,LimitsPositioningTokens->{}]` with restarting *Mathematica* does not show any difference (I have saved and restored original value of this option before). BTW, the "\" symbol does not disappear when I enter it in the comment here.

Comment: @Sjoerd Now I see your point, thank you. It seems that `LimitsPositioningTokens` should not affect input interpretation and it is good to know that this bug is fixed in version 8.0.1.

Comment: @Sjoerd I accept your answer. Up to this moment no other dangerous symbol names suggested in this thread and so I hope that there are no other dangerous symbols names starting with a lowercase letter in *Mathematica*. The only thing that is really confusing me is that such hazardous bug persisted so long time (from at least v.5 up to v.7).